# LaTeX2rtf with pdftooltip

Tags: environments, pdfcomment, latex2rtf

I'm using LaTeX2rtf to convert LaTeX article or report documents into rich text format. I also compile the PDF using pdfLaTeX. In my document, I use the [`pdfcomment`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment) package to create tooltips.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
\pdftooltip{$a^2+b^2=c^2$}{An equation}
\end{document}
```

The tooltips are correctly rendered in the PDF version.

However, when I run

```
latex2rtf
```

`\pdftooltip[*options*]{*item*}{*tooltip*}` is rendered as *item* and *tooltip*. If *item* is a float, or equation, then the float or equation is shown. *tooltip* is always shown as text.

This is correct as far as LaTeX2rtf is concerned, but I would like to modify this behavior so that I don't have to tidy up my document too much.

Question: How can I force LaTeX2rtf to ignore *tooltip* and just process the *item* argument? I am looking for a solution that will work with a document that contains lots of `\pdftooltips`, so using the `\iflatextortf` switch doesn't really work (too much added complexity). Ideally I would be able to define something in the preamble or pass an option to LaTeX2rtf.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without modifications to the latex2rtf program code, the only way is conditional processing. Latex2rtf automatically sets the `\iflatex2rtf` condition true, while for pdflatex it is false by default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\newif\iflatextortf
\begin{document}
\iflatextortf
$a^2+b^2=c^2$
\else
\pdftooltip{$a^2+b^2=c^2$}{An equation}
\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Close! This would work if I had one or two `\pdftooltips' to deal with. Unfortunately I need this to work in documents with many of these. I've modified the original request to reflect this.

Comment: @Wilfried; I took your suggestion and used the `\iflatextortf` switch in the preamble. There I defined a new `\pdfcomment` as `\newcommand{\pdftooltip}[3][]{#2}`. My document now compiles nicely in both PDFLatex and latextortf, with no re-writing.